# Wordpress custom post type menu generation

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

**The problem:** I have a site (under development) where I have generated a custom post type called "Products" . Inside I have different categories and posts. I would like to generate a menu like behaviour to my sidebar, but using google I haven't really stumbled onto something good. Who knows, maybe my idea is all wrong and is doable using some other solution.

Currently I have used WP Query to echo out all posts under one category. So this means that I have to manually copy code to echo new category with its posts when it is created. One solution is to create a menu manually, but i'd like to keep it auto-generated because users are not keen to do extra work and ofter forgot how it is done.

**So, the question**: Is my solution all wrong? How can i achieve menu like behaviour with class active for clicked category and its sub item? Is it better to just use pages?

**Example of my code:**

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'cat' => 1
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($query->have_posts()) {

    echo '<ul>';

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>Category name, title</li>

        <li class="cpt-menu-item" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>

        <?php endwhile;

    echo '</ul>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: You can get the different categories with the function `get_terms`. Once you have the categories, you can loop through them to query the posts from each category.